# Slide-out panel not resetting as expected

Tags: jquery, position, panel, slide

I am currently working on a jquery tab-slide out plugin available here:
http://www.atwebpresence.com/client/orto/index.html

Issue:
The 3 tabs on the top should slide-down and go back to the original position when closed. The original position is:

```
top: 70px;
position: fixed;
```

However, when I open that tab these change to:

```
left: 0px;
```

And when I close them the following attributes are set:

```
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
```

I would like to achieve the following:
- Left attribute to be unchanged
- top attribute to re-set to 70px when the tab is closed.

I hope this is clear enough. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
$('.tab').on('click', function() {
   var t = $(this);
   var e = $('.slide');
   // If already open
   if (t.hasClass('open')) {
      // Reset position of slide element & remove classname
      t.removeClass('open');
      e.css({ 'left' : '0px', 'top' : '0px' });
   } else {
      // Assign classname to tab and pull element out
      t.addClass('open');
      e.css({ 'left' : '0px' });
   }
});
```

Comment: Hi Jamie, thank you for your comment. At the moment the only script used call the library that controls the plugin is the following:

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
 function initApp() {
  oe24TabMenu = new e24TabMenu( 'tabslide', { mode: 'uppertabs', duration: 0.5, transition: Effect.Transitions.sinoidal } ); 
 }
 Event.observe(window, 'load', initApp, false);
// -->
</script>

I am not 100% sure how I can put your solution in place.